# Jquery Ajax parse error while retrieving file from servlet

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, servlets, pdf

I am creating PDF file in server side and on returning this on servlet request. I am retrieving this using jquery ajax call, but is is giving me parse error, what could be reason?

**server side code**

```
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
String fileName = "Vendormaster.pdf";
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\"" + fileName  + "\"");
RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile("D:/PDF_1.pdf", "r");
byte[] pdfBytes= new byte[(int)f.length()];
f.read(pdfBytes);
ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
response.setContentLength(pdfBytes.length);
out.write(pdfBytes);
out.flush();
```

**Ajax call**

```
function GetData(url){  var dataObject=[];  $.ajax({

        url : url,
        type : "GET",
        async : false,
        dataType : 'json',
        contentType : "application/json",
        beforeSend:function(){ //           $("#ajaxloader").fadeIn();      },
        success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {        dataObject= data; //        $("#ajaxloader").fadeOut(0);

        },
        error : function(data,b,c) {
            var error; //           $("#ajaxloader").fadeOut(0);
                return null;
        }
```

**Header from Live Http headers**

> GET /vendor_master_new/PdfGen HTTP/1.1 Host: xx.xx.xxx.xx:50000
>   Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
>   Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
>   Content-Type: application/json Cookie: saplb_*=(J2EE3952620)3952650;
>   MYSAPSSO2=AjExMDAgABRwb3J0YWw6QWRtaW5pc3RyYXRvcogAB2RlZmF1bHQBAAACAAMwMDADAANFUDEEAAwyMDE0MDgyNjAyNDEFAAQAAAAICgAA%2FwEEMIIBAAYJKoZIhvcNAQcCoIHyMIHvAgEBMQswCQYFKw4DAhoFADALBgkqhkiG9w0BBwExgc8wgcwCAQEwIjAdMQwwCgYDVQQDEwNFUDExDTALBgNVBAsTBEoyRUUCAQAwCQYFKw4DAhoFAKBdMBgGCSqGSIb3DQEJAzELBgkqhkiG9w0BBwEwHAYJKoZIhvcNAQkFMQ8XDTE0MDgyNjAyNDEyMFowIwYJKoZIhvcNAQkEMRYEFNI0asgM56O%2FhRIw9maLcMVSFKjLMAkGByqGSM44BAMELjAsAhRVFdOnzxSD1X6!YYuN3rFTWD4QGwIUa6cOuiyvPzHS355ksX7!%2Ft5az3c%3D;
>   JSESSIONID=olcptllrixgcMgn5_xL0y4mRZzAQSAEKUDwA_SAP-1UuLDj55yIZYsgUl10Rvcmd;
>   JSESSIONMARKID=ccttaAveOF7gPQfOE5gGjfKliPgTAVLdbcRwpQPAA Referer:
>   http://xx.xx.xxx.xx:50000/vendor_master_new/vendorMaster.html
>   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36
>   (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safari/537.36
>   X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
>
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK content-disposition: attachment;
>   filename="Vendormaster.pdf" content-length: 480288 content-type:
>   application/pdf date: Tue, 26 Aug 2014 03:10:54 GMT expires: Thu, 01
>   Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT pragma: no-cache server: SAP NetWeaver
>   Application Server 7.41 / AS Java 7.40

Comment: because you return raw pdf file. It's not json format.

Comment: No idea what you're trying to do with binary PDF data in your page, but the actual issue is similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25297982/display-image-in-html-which-is-returned-as-a-mime-media-type-from-an-ajax-call/25299278#25299278).

Comment: 1. Change your contentType in ajax call to what you set in server [application/pdf] 2. Refer this SO post, it is almost duplicate  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186562/post-to-server-receive-pdf-deliver-to-user-w-jquery